# how to show new added columns in database in yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

i added two new columns in my db table, and then i defined these new columns in the table model itself, and then, when i called

```
$model->getAttributes()
```

the two new columns didn't appear in the array output of `$model->getAttributes() method call`

there's no schema caching set in my configs,
any idea how to solve this?, and how am I gonna get the value of the input forms
of the new added columns from the front-end if i have a problem in showing off the two newly added columns ?

e.g

new columns
         INHOUSE
         OUTHOUSE

//view

```
 <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'INHOUSE',array("id"=>"inhouse","value"=>1, "uncheckValue"=>0));?>
 <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'OUTHOUSE',array("id"=>"outhouse","value"=>1, "uncheckValue"=>0));?>
```

//controller update action

i tried to save the value of the INHOUSE and OUTHOUSE didn't get saved when i do

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['users'];
$model->save();
```

NOR

```
$model->INHOUSE = $_POST['users']['INHOUSE'];
$model->OUTHOUSE = $_POST['users']['OUTHOUSE'];
$model->save;
```

any ideas how to solve all those problems?

Comment: Let's see the actual model code (including rules).

Comment: columns are in the safe mode of my rules

Comment: can you directly enter values in the db? i think this is a db error, so please confirm that. Plus you don't need to have those columns in the safe rule for this, getAttributes always uses metadata, hence there is no question about safe, or unsafe. Infact for the getAttributes call you don't need to change anything in the model to reflect newly added columns.

Comment: there's something wrong with oracle, that's why I had a problem saving the data from a simple checkbox.... note to self: when using yii framework and oracle database, and then in future, new columns are added,,yii will not show them on the spot unlike mysql.. there is a script needed to be executed for the new schema so that yii framework can show the new table columns via $model->getAttributes() and save data in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-Can you insert data directly into your DB on those columns?
2-Can you view those columns on the admin view or on any other view?
3-Can you retrieve those values using a getColumn method?

If not, try this:

Make sure that you have the new columns specified in your model and view

Model_Name.php

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID', // example
        'new_column' => 'New Column',
        ...
    );
}
```

You should also check from TOP to bottom and as a good practice you should also type this on the top of the model

```
 * @property integer $id //example
 * @property data_type $new_column
...
```

Then to view your new columns you need to add them to the necessary views.

example

VIEW.PHP

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
         'id',
         'new_column',
          ...
```

If you have your model with all these definitions you should be able to retrieve those values from the DB, re-check any custom functions that you may have.

Comment: this is not the answer to my problem....anyway, the solution for this is that, we ran an sql script whenever there's a new added table or column or some alterations in the db tables...

Answer (score 5):

Please goto to : protected/runtime folder and delete all files. And try again.