# Yii Model not fetching the newly added columns, Mysql Cache Issue

Tags: php, mysql, caching, yii, rds

I have mysql db stored on rds. Recently i had to add few columns into my tables.
I made the changes in the models accordingly. But none of them are fetching the newly added columns, although if i am making any changes to the data in the already existing columns, changes are being fetched perfectly. But new columns are not being fetched.

I have tried to reset or flush the query cache but no success..

Tried connecting development database with the same changes in the db and code, and it worked perfectly, but changes aren't being fetched from the production database.

Mysql engine for production db is "MySQL 5.6.19a " with multi AZ enabled.

Can anyone suggest what to do to get the new added columns?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using yii1 or yii2? and you get error when try accessing (assign or save) to these field?

Comment: yii1 (1.1.17)..and i am not able to access these fields where model says "field_xyz" is not defined..although it is there in db and model as well..

Comment: Strange thing is i am able to get the data using createCommand..by using query..

Comment: Just in case anybody looking for solution..I end up cloning the database with a new name..and then things worked perfectly..

Comment: then is somethings.. related to yii chache management ... in yii2 when this happen is possible delete the runtime directory .. but in yii1 this feature is not suitable ..

Comment: Yes i think so, but thing is if its the issue with cache, why would it work with development environment and not with production?
All i can guess is Yii 1.1 has compatibility issue with mysql 5.6..may be, not sure..

Answer (score 0):

already answered at:

[yii-model-not-fetching-the-newly-added-columns-mysql-cache-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041262/how-to-show-new-added-columns-in-database-in-yii-framework)

1. Make sure that you have the new columns specified in your model and view
2. **Go to protected/runtime folder and delete all files. And try again**
3. Add label attributes (if the new column is to be modified by user inputs)
4. Verify relations (if this new column is a foreign key)
5. Modify the search method (generated by yiic..if you use it of course)

Comment: Read the question again. Thanks.